# Web Scrapping options from dropdown with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get a list of all the airports from https://www.flight-distance.com/ Select Origin dropdown. I have managed to get the start of the data with the below code. but I can't figure out how to get all the options from the site as shown in the attached image.(Only starting to learn Python)

So for eg. the list would start with
Goroka (GKA, AYGA),
Madang (MAG, AYMD),
Mount Hagen (HGU, AYMH),
etc.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get("http://www.flight-distance.com/")
#type(r)
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
all=soup.find_all("select",{"id":"source_airport"})
all
```

Result:

```
> [<select class="form-control single_sel_air" id="source_airport"
> name="source_airport">  <option value="">Please select airport or
> city</option>  </select>]
```

[image: Airports]

Really appreciate any and all help

Comment: You either want to select `option` elements and get first "x" of them, or you should select `children elements` from `select` - there should be function/method that gets children elements from tag.

Comment: You should accept @Sergey K answer from below, if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the page loads, the list of airports is loaded dynamically, you can do it like this:

```
url = 'https://www.flight-distance.com/get_airports'
response = requests.get(url)
for airport in response.json()['data']:
    print(airport['Name'], airport['IATA_FAA'], airport['ICAO'])
```

OUTPUT:

```
Goroka GKA AYGA
Madang MAG AYMD
Mount Hagen HGU AYMH
Nadzab LAE AYNZ
Port Moresby Jacksons Intl POM AYPY
Wewak Intl WWK AYWK
Narsarsuaq UAK BGBW
Nuuk GOH BGGH
Sondre Stromfjord SFJ BGSF
Thule Air Base THU BGTL
Akureyri AEY BIAR
Egilsstadir EGS BIEG
Hornafjordur HFN BIHN
Husavik HZK BIHU
Isafjordur IFJ BIIS
Keflavik Nas KEF BIKF
Patreksfjordur PFJ BIPA
Reykjavik RKV BIRK
Siglufjordur SIJ BISI
...........
```

Comment: additional Question, how would I get the results to include the Brackets and commas, etc. as in show Goroka (GKA, AYGA) Not Goroka GKA AYGA? Thanks Again

Comment: print(f"{airport['Name']} ({airport['IATA_FAA']}, {airport['ICAO']})")